# Multipart FormData é uma estrutura de dados?

Tags: formdata

Como funciona "por trás dos panos".

Sei que quando enviamos uma requisição e o corpo definimos como JSON, isso é uma estrutura de dados que será enviada em formado JSON, no caso, o Multipart FormData também é uma estrutura de dados? Como ela funciona?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`multipart/form-data` não é uma estrutura de dados mas sim uma de três formas de codificação que temos no HTML:

- `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (the default)
- `multipart/form-data`
- `text/plain`

De uma forma geral as especificações do formato não importam para a maioria dos developers mas os pontos importantes são:

- Nunca usar `text/plain`.

Do lado do cliente:

- Usar `multipart/form-data` quando o form inclui algum elemento do tipo `<input type="file">`
- Caso contrário, pode-se utilizar `multipart/form-data` ou `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` mas `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` é mais eficiente.

[Esta questão](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28380690/3990896) tem uns exemplos com bastante detalhe e a qual já recorri em algumas explicações, e também a justificação do porquê de utilizar um ou outro conforme descrevi nos pontos acima, sendo que a diferença entre os tipos de codificação está na forma como ambos lidam com caracteres não imprimíveis.

Comment: Oi, Iam, bom dia! Por que "Nunca usar text/plain."?

Comment: A codificação "text/plain", introduzida como parte da especificação do HTML5, na verdade, não tem nenhum tipo de codificação e o seu único objetivo é permitir a leitura humana não sendo a interpretação pela máquina fiável.

Answer (score 7):

O `multipart/form-data` representa um tipo de conteúdo que será submetido ao servidor da mesma forma que um `application/json`. A diferença
é a origem da requisição. Se a mesma tiver sua origem em um formulário HTML, podemos trabalhar apenas com os seguintes tipos:

- application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- multipart/form-data
- text/plain

Por outro lado, se a origem for uma aplicação ou uma requisição AJAX, podemos trabalhar com `application/json` e adicionar o JSON no body.

Por exemplo, um formulário com o `enctype=application/x-www-form-urlencoded` tem seus campos representados na seguinte estrutura: 
`campo1=valor1&campo2=valor2&...`. Já no caso do `multipart/form-data` os dados são representados através de várias partes, onde 
cada parte pode ter seu próprio MIME type:

```
--<<boundary_value>>
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="campo1"

valor1
--<<boundary_value>>
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="campo2"
Content-Type: text/html

valor2
--<<boundary_value>>--
```

Basicamente cada parte é delimitada pelo `boundary` e possuí na primeira linha a estrutura `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="NOME DO MEU CAMPO"`. 
Na sequência, separando as informações por CR LR, opcionalmente pode-se declarar o `Content-type`, que por padrão é `text/plain`. Por fim, vêm o valor 
do campo.

Se quiser mais detalhes, dê uma lida neste link: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#idx-character_encoding

Então da mesma forma que um JSON é representado pela estrutura de chaves/valores, estes tipos de conteúdo também tem sua própria estrutura
de representação.